# Program that can split a line of characters into what comes before and after numbers

Tags: c#, excel, vba

Example:

"Member, Guidelines Committee, American Society of Interventional Pain Physicians, 2006 – present"
would become...
"Member, Guidelines Committee, American Society of Interventional Pain Physicians, "
AND "2006 – present"

I want to know:
A) what language would be best for this, How would it be parsed, or split, how could it be taken out of an Excel spreadsheet (instead of a simple text-box, or a console.read), then put back into Excel, in two different cells.

Comment: Please do not [double post](http://superuser.com/questions/320580/split-a-string-in-a-cell-in-excel-using-numbers-as-the-divider).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBA is preferable here since you are working with Excel. Here is some code that will go through each cell in column A and split them at the first number.

```vb
Sub SplitCells()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim currentValue As String

lastRow = cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row

For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
    currentValue = cells(i, "A").Value
    For j = 1 To Len(currentValue)
        If IsNumeric(Mid$(currentValue, j, 1)) = True Then
            cells(i + 1, "A").EntireRow.Insert
            cells(i, "A").Value = Left$(currentValue, j - 1)
            cells(i + 1, "A").Value = Mid$(currentValue, j)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

**How it works**: It's very important to loop through the column backwards so when you insert rows you aren't messing with the loop. It just looks through each cell for the first numeric value and when it find one, it splits it, putting everything after the numeric value in the new row and cutting that portion out of the current cell. You can alter the range to be whatever you wish.

Answer (score 0):

use C# - declare a class like this

```
public class Info
{
    private string _status;
    private string _committee;
    private string _comName;
    private string _dateperiod;

    public string getFormattedvalue
    {
        get 
        {
            return _status +", "+
                _committee +", "+
                _comName;
        }
    }

    public string formattedDate
    {
        get
        {
            return _dateperiod;
        }
    }

    public Info(string input)
    {
        string[] s = input.Split(',');
        _status = s[0];
        _committee = s[1];
        _comName = s[2];
        _dateperiod = s[3];
    }

}
```

Comment: I would highly suggest against using C# for an operation like this since it can easily be done via VBA. Plus your class declaration doesn't give the OP any clue on how to do the operation he wants to do.